# Unzip to pipe and then run PDF info on the files in the stream

Tags: bash, pdf, command-line, find, unzip

I want to unzip a LOT of files and then run pdfinfo to get the page count for each file and the sum those page counts.

I came across a command that will sum the pages of all pages in a directory.

```
find . -name \*.pdf -exec pdfinfo {} \; | grep Pages | sed -e "s/Pages:\s*//g" | awk '{ sum += $1;} END { print sum; }'
```

I then thought to pipe that into #unzip -p

```
unzip -p '*.zip' | find . -name \*.pdf -exec pdfinfo {} \; | grep Pages | sed -e "s/Pages:\s*//g" | awk '{ sum += $1;} END { print sum; }'
```

However it's not working as I expect it to. I suspect that my unzip stream is interacting poorly with the find.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: find does need to take the output of unzip so they are seperate commands. you can connect them with `&&` instead of a pipe. or just run pdfinfo without find

Comment: Try running `echo \`unzip -p '*.zip\`` to check the output of unzip to pipe. Also, `find`command is not reading anything from stdin.

Comment: You can see more about what you are trying to do here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56430/is-it-possible-to-run-shell-commands-inside-zip-files I'm afraid the best way to what you want is to extract all files and then run the oneliner you got.

Comment: There should be a way to stream the unzip to a command to act upon. Extractinng 5TB of zip files is not going to be awesome

Comment: @gabrielsimoes You're right the find command is not reading anything from the standard in. I could leave it off

Comment: I don't think you can access your files without extracting them.

Comment: The best you can do is to extract only the pdf files, as shown here: https://superuser.com/a/462796

Comment: with extra resources (machines, cpus,code, etc) you can parallelize your task (but that will take more time to set up). Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it that doesn't write anything to the filesystem. This code should work if any of the filenames in the zip files contain embedded whitespace. The code assumes that filenames ending in "pdf" are valid PDF files.

This is the test zip file I'm going to use. Note that the first filename in the zip archive, "zlib 3.pdf", contains a space character.

```
$ unzip -l aaa.zip 
Archive:  aaa.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
    19318  2018-02-19 22:49   zlib 3.pdf
   442780  2018-02-28 15:32   file2.pdf
      757  2018-02-28 15:22   try.sh
---------                     -------
   462855                     3 files
```

It turns out that `pdfinfo` can read from stdin, so the command below shows how to get the number of pages from a pdf stored in a zip without writing anything to disk.

```
$ unzip -p aaa.zip file2.pdf | pdfinfo - | grep Pages
Pages:          94

$ unzip -p aaa.zip "zlib 3.pdf" | pdfinfo - | grep Pages
Pages:          2
```

For this to work though, you need to know the names of the PDF files stored in the zip archive.

The next step then is to get a list of the PDF files and the names of the zip files they are stored in. That's what this code does

```
for zip in *.zip ; do 
    echo $zip
    zipinfo -1 "$zip" | grep 'pdf$'| while read pdf
    do
        echo "  '$pdf'" 
    done  
done
```

That outputs this for me

```
aaa.zip
  'zlib 3.pdf'
  'file2.pdf'
```

Finally add the code to call `pdfinfo` and the awk code snippet to work out the total number of pages.

```
for zip in *.zip ; do 
    zipinfo -1 "$zip" | grep 'pdf$'| while read pdf
    do
        unzip  -p "$zip" "$pdf" | pdfinfo - | grep Pages | sed -e "s/Pages:\s*//g"
    done  
done | awk '{ sum += $1;} END { print sum; }'
```

That outputs 96 for my test zip file.

Comment: Sorry didn't work for me got a lot of illegal filename

Comment: Can you check which command is complaining about the illegal filenames? One possibility is the filenames in the zip files contain whitespace. Can you show an sample of the filenames in the zip files?

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer to cope with zip archives that contain filename with embedded whitespace.

Comment: This is excellent! However I had to work with a developer to multithread the request because we are talking tereabytes of data. I suppose a way to multithread would be to stat the directory pipe to tee filename | split filename and then run multiple for loops

Answer (score 0):

If diskspace is your main concern, this will probably help:

```
for zip in *.zip ;do
    for pdf in $(unzip -l "$zip"  | grep 'pdf$' | cut -c31-) ; do
        unzip "$zip" "$pdf"
        pdfinfo "$pdf" | sed -n "s/Pages:\s*//p"
        rm "$pdf"
     done | paste -s -d+ - | bc
done
```

Comment: Got a lot of illegal filename and individual character count attempts

Answer (score 0):

Similar to my need to extract .FLAC audio files from a zip archive and convert to .OPUS on the fly. This worked for me. First I had to make a separate text file of the filenames to extract from each zip archive. There is no easy way around this since piping works but doesn't pass file names. Once you have the list you just extract/convert each FLAC by name from the zip files, that way you know what to name each OPUS file.

This relies on the unzip -p option to pipe output.

```
for zip in *.zip
  do 
    zipinfo -1 "$zip" | grep flac > "$zip"_flacs.txt;
    printf -- zip\:...."$zip\n"flac\:..."$flac\n";
    cat "$zip"_flacs.txt | while read flac
      do 
        printf "extracting $flac \n";
        unzip -p "$zip" "$flac" | ffmpeg -i - -ab 256k "${flac%.*}.opus";
      done
    done
```

Don't forget to extract everything else.

```
for zip in *zip; do unzip "$zip" -x *.flac *.mp4; done
```